# linux-xlnx: Kernel hangs at Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm attempting to get a persistent distribution (Linaro) on an SD card, up and running on the ZedBoard. I built the kernel from the linux-xlnx source, and have run into a number of issues during startup. I've managed to overcome most of the kernel hangs I've been experiencing at bootup, but I'm stuck at "Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler".

I've noticed an option in the .config file "CONFIG_SWP_EMULATE=y", but even if I comment this out (and I don't know if I should be doing this anyway, to be honest), when I go to rebuild the kernel with "make UIMAGE_LOADADDR=0x8000 uImage", this line just gets re-enabled in the .config file for whatever reason, and the problem persists.

The original configuration was created using "make xilinx_zynq_defconfig". I then used "make menuconfig" to enable earlyprintk and low-level debugging in the kernel hacking menu (displaying the output on UART1). From there, I directly edited the .config file each time the kernel got stuck at some point. The notable changes from the "xilinx_zynq_defconfig" thus far are:

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_LL=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_ZYNQ_UART1=y
CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK=y
# CONFIG_SERIAL_XILINX_PS_UART is not set
# CONFIG_RTC_HCTOSYS is not set
CONFIG_ARM_THUMB=y
CONFIG_ARM_THUMBEE=y
```

Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue would be appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

```
U-Boot 2016.07-00057-g2931a7a-dirty (Nov 17 2016 - 02:58:29 -0500)

Model: Zynq Zed Development Board
Board: Xilinx Zynq
DRAM:  ECC disabled 512 MiB
MMC:   sdhci@e0100000: 0
SF: Detected S25FL256S_64K with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 32 MiB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial@e0001000
Out:   serial@e0001000
Err:   serial@e0001000
Model: Zynq Zed Development Board
Board: Xilinx Zynq
Net:   ZYNQ GEM: e000b000, phyaddr 0, interface rgmii-id
eth0: ethernet@e000b000
reading uEnv.txt
135 bytes read in 10 ms (12.7 KiB/s)
Importing environment from SD ...
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Device: sdhci@e0100000
Manufacturer ID: 28
OEM: 4245
Name: 2$AGO 
Tran Speed: 50000000
Rd Block Len: 512
SD version 3.0
High Capacity: Yes
Capacity: 7.5 GiB
Bus Width: 4-bit
Erase Group Size: 512 Bytes
reading uEnv.txt
135 bytes read in 10 ms (12.7 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from SD ...
Copying Linux from SD to RAM...
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 02080000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-4.6.0-xilinx-00040-g786228
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3828432 Bytes = 3.7 MiB
   Load Address: 00008000
   Entry Point:  00008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 02020000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x2020000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 1eb0e000, end 1eb13595 ... OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Linux version 4.6.0-xilinx-00040-g7862283 (steven@sjk) (gcc version 4.9.2 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2015.05-17) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 17 20:58:49 EST 2016
CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc090] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=18c5387d
CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
Machine model: Zynq Zed Development Board
bootconsole [earlycon0] enabled
cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x1f000000
Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
On node 0 totalpages: 131072
free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c0938a80, node_mem_map debef000
  Normal zone: 1024 pages used for memmap
  Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
  Normal zone: 131072 pages, LIFO batch:31
percpu: Embedded 12 pages/cpu @debcd000 s19776 r8192 d21184 u49152
pcpu-alloc: s19776 r8192 d21184 u49152 alloc=12*4096
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 130048
Kernel command line: console=ttyACM0,115200 debug root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw earlyprintk=serial,uart1,115200 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait devtmpfs.mount=0
PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
Memory: 494532K/524288K available (5303K kernel code, 229K rwdata, 1836K rodata, 1024K init, 221K bss, 13372K reserved, 16384K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)
Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xe0800000 - 0xff800000   ( 496 MB)
    lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xe0000000   ( 512 MB)
    pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
    modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
      .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc07f8d68   (8132 kB)
      .init : 0xc0800000 - 0xc0900000   (1024 kB)
      .data : 0xc0900000 - 0xc09397e0   ( 230 kB)
       .bss : 0xc09397e0 - 0xc0970ee8   ( 222 kB)
Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
        Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
        RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=32, nr_cpu_ids=2
NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
efuse mapped to e0800000
slcr mapped to e0802000
L2C: platform modifies aux control register: 0x72360000 -> 0x72760000
L2C: DT/platform modifies aux control register: 0x72360000 -> 0x72760000
L2C-310 erratum 769419 enabled
L2C-310 enabling early BRESP for Cortex-A9
L2C-310 full line of zeros enabled for Cortex-A9
L2C-310 ID prefetch enabled, offset 1 lines
L2C-310 dynamic clock gating enabled, standby mode enabled
L2C-310 cache controller enabled, 8 ways, 512 kB
L2C-310: CACHE_ID 0x410000c8, AUX_CTRL 0x76760001
zynq_clock_init: clkc starts at e0802100
Zynq clock init
sched_clock: 64 bits at 333MHz, resolution 3ns, wraps every 4398046511103ns
clocksource: arm_global_timer: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x4ce07af025, max_idle_ns: 440795209040 ns
Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 3ns
clocksource: ttc_clocksource: mask: 0xffff max_cycles: 0xffff, max_idle_ns: 537538477 ns
timer #0 at e080a000, irq=17
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 666.66 BogoMIPS (lpj=3333333)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
Setting up static identity map for 0x100000 - 0x100058
CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
Brought up 2 CPUs
SMP: Total of 2 processors activated (1333.33 BogoMIPS).
CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
devtmpfs: initialized
VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant 9 rev 4
clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
NET: Registered protocol family 16
DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
cpuidle: using governor menu
hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
zynq-ocm f800c000.ocmc: ZYNQ OCM pool: 256 KiB @ 0xe0880000
zynq-pinctrl 700.pinctrl: zynq pinctrl initialized
vgaarb: loaded
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
media: Linux media interface: v0.10
Linux video capture interface: v2.00
pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
PTP clock support registered
EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
clocksource: Switched to clocksource arm_global_timer
NET: Registered protocol family 2
TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a9 PMU driver, 7 counters available
futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
workingset: timestamp_bits=28 max_order=17 bucket_order=0
jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) (SUMMARY)  �© 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
dma-pl330 f8003000.dmac: Loaded driver for PL330 DMAC-241330
dma-pl330 f8003000.dmac:        DBUFF-128x8bytes Num_Chans-8 Num_Peri-4 Num_Events-16
xdevcfg f8007000.devcfg: ioremap 0xf8007000 to e086c000
[drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
m25p80 spi0.0: found s25fl256s1, expected n25q128a11
m25p80 spi0.0: s25fl256s1 (32768 Kbytes)
5 ofpart partitions found on MTD device spi0.0
Creating 5 MTD partitions on "spi0.0":
0x000000000000-0x000000100000 : "qspi-fsbl-uboot"
0x000000100000-0x000000600000 : "qspi-linux"
0x000000600000-0x000000620000 : "qspi-device-tree"
0x000000620000-0x000000c00000 : "qspi-rootfs"
0x000000c00000-0x000001000000 : "qspi-bitstream"
CAN device driver interface
gpiod_set_value: invalid GPIO
libphy: MACB_mii_bus: probed
macb e000b000.ethernet eth0: Cadence GEM rev 0x00020118 at 0xe000b000 irq 145 (00:0a:35:00:01:22)
Marvell 88E1510 e000b000.etherne:00: attached PHY driver [Marvell 88E1510] (mii_bus:phy_addr=e000b000.etherne:00, irq=-1)
e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
e0002000.usb supply vbus not found, using dummy regulator
ULPI transceiver vendor/product ID 0x0451/0x1507
Found TI TUSB1210 ULPI transceiver.
ULPI integrity check: passed.
ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: EHCI Host Controller
ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
i2c /dev entries driver
EDAC MC: ECC not enabled
Xilinx Zynq CpuIdle Driver started
sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
mmc0: SDHCI controller on e0100000.sdhci [e0100000.sdhci] using DMA
ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
NET: Registered protocol family 10
sit: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
NET: Registered protocol family 17
can: controller area network core (rev 20120528 abi 9)
NET: Registered protocol family 29
can: raw protocol (rev 20120528)
mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 59b4
can: broadcast manager protocol (rev 20120528 t)
mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 2$AGO 7.46 GiB 
 mmcblk0: p1 p2
can: netlink gateway (rev 20130117) max_hops=1
ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
```